# Why app in docker container doesn't restart?

Tags: linux, docker, go, containers

I've deployed some docker containers with golang apps. One of them I need to start by this command:

```
docker run --restart unless-stopped -it myapp /bin/bash
```

The next step I enter the container and edit some config files, then I run

```
go build main.go
```

and `./main`
After that I press ctrl+q and leave it out.
Everything works perfectly and all my containers restart perfectly after restarting server. But there is one issue, when myapp container restarts, the golang application doesn't run while container still works. I have to enter this again and run `./main`. How can I fixed it?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM golang:1.8 
WORKDIR /go/src/app 
COPY . . 
RUN go-wrapper download # "go get -d -v ./..." 
RUN go-wrapper install # "go install -v ./..." RUN ["apt-get","update"] 
RUN ["apt-get","install","-y","vim"] 
EXPOSE 3000 
CMD ["app"]
```

Comment: Do your "editing" and build in the `Dockerfile` then `docker run --restart unless-stopped myapp main`

Comment: How does your Dockerfile look like. Are you setting the application to run on container start up?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @foecum I have changeable configs cause of network, that's why I have to edit container. Dockefile looks like: FROM golang:1.8

WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY . .

RUN go-wrapper download   # "go get -d -v ./..."
RUN go-wrapper install    # "go install -v ./..."
RUN ["apt-get","update"]
RUN ["apt-get","install","-y","vim"]
EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["app"]

Comment: My suggestion is for you to have different docker files to run that override the config that you are always editing. that way when the app is started you always have the correct config and you won't need to edit the file everytime

Comment: here is a link to the docker build/run options https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a container and pass in `/bin/bash` as the command, that's as far as Docker cares. When the container restarts, it will start up another instance of `/bin/bash`.

Docker doesn't watch your shell session and see what things you do after it starts the command. If you want to actually run `./main` as the command of the container, then you'll need to pass in `/go/src/app/main` as the command instead of `/bin/bash`.

Additionally, compiling code is something better done during the image build phase instead of at container runtime.